# Excel VBA Pasted Rows from filter are repeating data to the right

Tags: excel, vba, paste

When I paste data from a filtered range the data in the rows continuously repeat in the columns to the right until the last Excel column (XFD).  I am unable to determine the cause of my pasting issue. I am reusing code from a different project where code works as expected pasting only 1 instance of data. The copy/paste also works as expected when I manually paste the data, regardless of if the copying is done manually or by code. It's just the pasting that is acting differently.

In the current project, I have Filtered data in columns A to P and when I copy and paste then to another sheet all the data is continuously repeated to the right as presented in the generic example -

Copied Data:

| Header A | Header B |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |
| a6 | b6 |

Pasted Data:

| Header A | Header B | Header C | Header D | Header E | Header F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | a1 | b1 | a1 | b1 |
| a6 | b6 | a6 | b6 | a6 | b6 |

Copy Code:

```
Set rngFilter = Range("A1:P3472")
rngFilter.Parent.Select
rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:13, Criteria1:="=*criteria*"
rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
```

Paste Code:

```
Worksheets(2).Rows("16:16").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
```

Comment: You are pasting it to the entire row `Worksheets(2).Rows("16:16").Select`  Change that to just the range you want. `Worksheets(2).Rows("A16").Select`

Comment: Also.  Using `.Select` is slow and should be avoided.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba